# zybooks for python, whotespace issue

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu1SX.png)

so I keep getting these whitespaces in my output. I have googled  but nothing relevant comes back. i have attached my code and my output. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong. I dont have any space in my code, so why is it putting it in my ouput? this is a common problem form me in zybooks and i would really love to know what i am doing wrong so i can get this done and move on to the next assignment without spending 2 hours on a simple exercise.

Comment: not sure if you can see my screenshots. so my code is:   password1 = favoriteColor

print('\nFirst password:', favoriteColor,chr(95),petName)
print('Second password:', num,favoriteColor,num)                                       this is what prints out:    First password: yellow _ Daisy
Second password: 6 yellow 6              there should not be space between yellow and '_' or "_' and Daisy as well as between the 6's or yellow in the 2nd password

Comment: 1) Don't post code as images, paste it directly into your question and format it as code (use the `{}` button) 2) There's no output shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking why there are spaces between your outputs of `favoriteColor`, etc., it's because Python's `print` function automatically adds spaces between each of its arguments. If you don't want this happening, you can change your code in two ways:

Either add a `sep` argument to your print, telling Python to add an empty separator between your arguments:

```
print('\nFirst password:', favoriteColor, chr(95), petName, sep='')
```

Or, you can append your arguments together yourself, as strings:

```
print('\nFirst password:', favoriteColor + chr(95) + petName)
```

Also, I should mention that if you need an underscore, you don't need to call `chr(95)` -- you can just write the string `'_'`.

Comment: thank you! im new to this.. 1st class.. chapter 3.. zybooks seems kind of difficult to work with. it errored when i just typed the '_'

Comment: No problem. It's very unusual about the underscore, but whatever works :) Also, in the future, please post your code directly, instead of posting screenshots. Good luck with your course!

Comment: thanks! so on a related note.. same prblem just a bit different:            
cansNeeded = math.ceil(paintNeeded)
print('Cans needed:' , cansNeeded, 'can(s)')

# FIXME (4): Calculate and output the total cost of paint can needed depending on color
colorChoice = input('\nChoose a color to paint the wall:')
print('\nCost of purchasing', colorChoice , 'paint:', '$',(paintColors[colorChoice] * cansNeeded))            It keeps giving me another white space between the '$' and the number.

Comment: if i use the sep='' it puts all the words together, if i use '+' it errors something about an integer and a string.